# Codeigniter URI Routing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have check the codeigniter user guide, But I was not lucky to solve my problem.

I have created a webpage on my localhost.

When I go to `http://localhost/webpage/` it is okay. It will go to the default controller.

My default controller is `Homepage` and there are methods named `index`, `guarantee` and `about`

When I go to my routes.php, I added this:

```
$route['guarantee'] = "homepage/guarantee";
$route['about_us'] = "homepage/about";
```

Then try to access it `http://localhost/webpage/guarantee` and `http://localhost/webpage/about_us` it show ERROR 404

But when I do it like this `$route['default_controller'] = "homepage/guarantee";` The guarantee page will be displayed.

Can anyone help me with this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you any `.htaccess` file on this folder?

Comment: Inside the application folder, there is an `.htaccess`. I didn't touch it. It is a fresh copy of CodeIgniter i'm using..

Comment: This is ok, i just asked if you have added one to the root dir. Have you tried with `http://localhost/webpage/index.php/guarantee` ?

Comment: yes, It works. Thanks, But how can I remove the `index.php` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove index.php. In your application/config.php file change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then put this .htaccess file in your root folder (in the same folder as where index.php is:

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Set the default file for indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    # Activate URL rewriting:
RewriteEngine on

# do not rewrite links to the documentation, assets and public files
RewriteCond $1 !^(uploads|assets|js|css|images|img)


    # but rewrite everything else
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `application/config/config.php`, set `$config['index_page']` to empty like
`$config['index_page'] = '';` should work.